# rtabmap point cloud unit (m, mm, inch?)

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering how to set the unit that is used in the point cloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233684/rtabmap-point-cloud-unit-(m,-mm,-inch?)/) by [anonymous24903](https://answers.ros.org/users/24903/anonymous24903/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In meter.

Note that if the camera calibation is poor (focal distance is wrong), the scale may vary.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-05-07**:
Standard unis are defined in REP 103: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html